# IIS FTP Connectivity Issues

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003-r2

I seem to be having a strange connectivity problem at a client site where we are hosting an FTP site in IIS.  We also allow remote desktop connections to this server for troubleshooting purposes.

Whenever the client is experiencing these connectivity problems we are unable to connect to the ftp site or remote desktop.  The issue seems to be resolved if the client logs into the server and navigates to a website like google in Internet Explorer.

Could this be some kind of dns issue or something?  Looking for some suggestions.

#### Edit

The power scheme on the server is set to "Always On".  When I say the "client" logs into the server I mean they remote desktop on to the server from a workstation.  It appears that they did report an instance of where they remoted on to the server and communications began to start working again but soon failed so this may not be related.  They've also seen the same things from launching IE and navigating to a website.  This is a production server that has been there for awhile and we just started seeing these problems recently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say based on the information provided, but a couple of possibilities come to mind.

1. Sleep settings--especially if, when you say "the client logs into the server," you mean the client sits down physically in front of the server, wiggles the mouse, logs in, and launches a web browser.
2. Some sort of network hardware at the client site (firewall?) which has decided the server is asleep and doesn't actually need any packets, and/or is trying very hard to die.  (I generally see this happen more with VPN tunnels, but I don't know how your client has his network set up.)

Check the sleep/power save settings on the server.  If those are good, I'm afraid you're going to have to talk to the client's network team.  They're really the only people who can help you debug at that point.

Comment: I've added some additional information to my question to try and make it more clear.  Although I'm a little bit in the dark as well as we don't control our client's network and it's hard to get any details from them.